# Is concurrent execution of "sudo apt-get install", "sudo snap install", and "pip install --user " recommended?

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, snap, pip

To improve installation efficiency, I am thinking of conducting concurrent package installations when I have to use commands `sudo apt-get install`, `sudo snap install` and `pip install --user`  in a script.

Is this a good idea, or, is this a bad idea (i.e. it can be disastrous for either the Linux OS or computer hardware like storage medium)? Any pitfall(s) that I should look out for when doing this?

Comment: If you attempt to use `apt` and `pip` to simultaneously install *the same package*, you may encounter serious problems. Both install to the same locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system will not allow executing `apt install` more than once at a time. it will error out on the 2nd one because it can not lock a special file. Reason: `apt remove` and  `apt install` can have conflicting actions. One package could need to remove something that the other action would need. "Dependency hell" is what we called that.

"snap" can do it but you need a special feature:

```
snap set system experimental.parallel-instances=true
```

There will be no problems: "snap" is designed to be independent of everything. There is no dependency issue here: all snaps install their own software.

"pip" can do it too.

```
xargs --max-args=1 --max-procs=4 sudo pip install < install.txt
```

it will install the packages that are in "install.txt" (each line one package) and it will install (in this example) 4 at a time. Be careful: this can get nasty with dependencies. `pipenv install package packages` is supposed to fix the dependencies problem but has a serious drawback: it creates a file and a lock file that takes long to create so not much gain in speed. But it does install in parallel when done.

Assuming you meant to use each of these 3 at the same time (and not one of these 3 more than once at the same time): You can have 1 of each of these running at the same time where snap and pip can do parallel installs. Also with a note to take into account: it is possible to use `apt` to install a package that also can be installed with `pip`. Do that at the same time and it could spell trouble.

[As said in comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169160/is-concurrent-execution-of-sudo-apt-get-install-sudo-snap-install-and-pip/1169177?noredirect=1#comment1950769_1169160): always do a `sudo apt update` before installing new software.

> Is concurrent execution of “sudo apt-get install”, “sudo snap install”, and “pip install --user ” recommended?

No but "recommended" is not really a show stopper :)

Comment: Can I use python3's `concurrent.futures` to host various `subprocess.run()` process that will run the `apt-get install` cmd alongside your parallised `snap` and `pip` commands? Or should I confine all the concurrent/parallel management to `concurrent.futures`?

Comment: Sure. Like I said: you can not do that with apt install more than once at the same time. I would make 1 apt install (and add all the packages on 1 line) You will win some of  the time it takes to install the largest of the snap or pip installations.